# Unable to Upgrade SaltStack

Tags: ubuntu, salt-stack

I am trying to upgrade my saltstack master and minion on ubuntu following steps in blog
http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/16/upgrade-salt-master-and-minions-ubuntu-servers/

But i get the following error
Step 1 : sudo salt ‘*’ cmd.run “aptitude update”
[image]

Step 2 : Update Master
[image]

Step 3 : Update Minion
[image]

**I want to upgrade to 2015.8.6**

I suspect something is not working in step 1.

Present Ubuntu version.

[image]

**Did the following ,** 
*
1) on running fgrep -lR "saltstack" , it gives only master file

2) and i opened master file i could see saltstack only in comments. so didnt make any changes there

3) wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/14.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add -
--2016-04-15 17:58:34--  https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/14.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
Resolving repo.saltstack.com (repo.saltstack.com)... nnn.nnn.nn.nnn, 2805:a770:450:a0::2:d001
Connecting to repo.saltstack.com (repo.saltstack.com)|nnn.nnn.nn.nnn|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1744 (1.7K)
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 1,744       --.-K/s   in 0s
2016-04-15 17:58:36 (14.1 MB/s) - written to stdout [1744/1744]
OK

4) on running 'sudo apt-get update' get error W: GPG error: https://packages.elastic.co stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D38D777CD99E42A4*

Comment: ppa.launchpad.net is an old repository.  The new repo are repo.saltstack.com

Comment: When "apt-get update" encounter OTHER repo package error, it will stop , even saltstack repo is ok.  You need to fix the  signature for packages.elastic.co  in your /etc/apt/souces.list  or inside sources.list.d folder , or just remark them you don't need it.  
Reference to fix repo with signatures error: 
https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/

Comment: You have elastic search repo with signature error, just fix it and run apt-get update again. 

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cleanup the old PPA that point to http://ppa.launchpad.net , this repo point to the old 2015.5 . That take me some effort to clean stuff out and point to repo.saltstack.com

```
# go to apt repo
cd /etc/apt

# find all old saltstack repo
fgrep -lR "saltstack"

#open each file,remove the entry that show saltstack

#Now grab the key 
wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/14.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add -

# Save following entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
deb http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/14.04/amd64/latest trusty main

#Now update repo
sudo apt-get update
```

The CORRECT documentation that show saltstack ubuntu repo is here :
http://repo.saltstack.com/#ubuntu

Comment: Hi , i tried steps that you gave , still getting error as above , any advice ? sorry a newbie to linux.